# mecab 中国語の辞書を作成について

Tags: python, twitter, mecab

[中国語の辞書を作成](http://www.onaneet.org/blog/archives/4020)をしたいですが、上手くいきません。
単語辞書から作成したいですが、何をどうして処理したらいいのかわかりません。 アドバイスを頂けませんか。

辞書作成　編集
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr
[root@localhost usr]# cd local
[root@localhost local]# cd etc
[root@localhost etc]# ls
mecabrc  mecabrc.in  mecabrc~
[root@localhost etc]#

Comment: 具体的にどこで詰まっていますか？リンクされている記事の作成手順にはあいまいなところもあるので（ソースを独自コンパイルするなど）、今の質問内容ですと「記事の通りにやってみてはどうでしょうか」程度のおおざっぱな回答しかできなさそうです。（中国語辞書を作ったことがあるぜ、という方があらわれない限り）

Answer (score 5):

奈良先端科学技術大学院大学(NAIST)　松本祐治研究室のHPに、MeCab用中国語辞書 公開リリースのページがあります。

[NAIST Chinese Dictionary](https://cl.naist.jp/index.php?%B8%F8%B3%AB%A5%EA%A5%BD%A1%BC%A5%B9%2FNCD)

利用に際しての手続きが必要なようですが、問い合わせてみてはどうでしょうか？